# How to execve an halt program?

Tags: exec, buffer-overflow

I'm trying an exploit where I'm creating a ROP gadget for halting the system. I need to execve halt program which shuts down the system. What are the arguments do I need to pass for execve to run that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass argument `/usr/bin/halt`, maybe something like this :

`execve("/usr/bin/halt", NULL, NULL)`